# データフレームからあるベクトルの要素を含む行だけを抜き出し、新しいデータフレームを作成したい

Tags: r

使用するデータフレームは以下のような形です。

```
name   year   price  
A社    1999    200    
A社    2000    202    
A社    2001    199    
A社    2002    400   
A社    2003    207    
B社    1999    300      
B社    2000    500     
B社    2001    201
```

「あるベクトル」とは、`[1] 199 200 201 202 207` です。

以上のデータフレームの変数priceの値が、ベクトルの要素と合致する行のみを残したいです。
目標は以下の形になります。

```
name   year   price  
A社    1999    200    
A社    2000    202    
A社    2001    199    
A社    2003    207    
B社    2001    201
```

Answer (score 1):

**Base R**

```r
df <- data.frame(
  "name" = c(rep("A社", 5), rep("B社", 3)),
  "year"  = c(1999:2003, 1999:2001),
  "price" = c(200, 202, 199, 400, 207, 300, 500, 201)
)

select_price <- c(199, 200, 201, 202, 207)

matched <- df[df$price %in% select_price,]

print(matched)

#
  name year price
1  A社 1999   200
2  A社 2000   202
3  A社 2001   199
5  A社 2003   207
8  B社 2001   201
```

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)

matched <- df %>% filter(price %in% select_price)

print(matched)

#
  name year price
1  A社 1999   200
2  A社 2000   202
3  A社 2001   199
4  A社 2003   207
5  B社 2001   201
```

※ `dplyr` の場合、インデックスがリセットされます。